# SQL with aggregated query result is not working

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE test_parent(id number,name varchar2(20));

CREATE TABLE test_child (
    id number NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    origin number NOT NULL,
    status number NOT NULL,
    parent_id number
);
```

origin: 1 > premium, 2 > fee, 3 > reject, 4> main premium

status: 10 > pending, 20 > cancelled, 30 > submitted

Need to get parent ids if it satisfied below points

Point 1:  origin > fee with or without ( premim or main premium) should come

Point 2:  status > (pending or (pending + cancelled)) should come

--parent insert

```
insert into test_parent values(1,'parent1');
insert into test_parent values(2,'parent2');
insert into test_parent values(3,'parent3');
insert into test_parent values(4,'parent4');
insert into test_parent values(5,'parent5');
insert into test_parent values(6,'parent6');
```

--Insert child ** for Parent 1 **:

```
insert into test_child values(1,1,10,1);
insert into test_child values(2,2,20,1);
insert into test_child values(3,2,10,1);
insert into test_child values(4,2,10,1);
```

--Insert child for Parent 2 shouldnt come:

```
insert into test_child values(5,3,10,2);
insert into test_child values(6,3,10,2);
insert into test_child values(7,1,10,2);
```

--Insert child for Parent 3 shouldnt come:

```
insert into test_child values(8,1,10,3);
insert into test_child values(9,1,30,3);
insert into test_child values(10,1,10,3);
```

--Insert child for Parent 4 shouldnt come:

```
insert into test_child values(11,1,10,4);
insert into test_child values(12,1,10,4);
insert into test_child values(13,1,10,4);
```

--Insert child for Parent**5 should come**:

```
insert into test_child values(14,2,10,5);
insert into test_child values(15,2,10,5);
```

I tried the below query but didn't work, please help with this. thanks.

**Update: I expect parent 1 and parent 5 ids as a result of this query.**

I need blue box parent ids but not orange
[image]

```
SELECT id,parent_id  FROM test_child
    WHERE   parent_id IN (
        SELECT parent_id FROM
            (
            SELECT parent_id, status, origin FROM
                (
                SELECT
                    child.parent_id,
                    child.status,
                    child.origin
                FROM
                    test_child child,
                    test_parent parent
                WHERE child.parent_id = parent.id
                
                ) tmp_table_inner)  tmp_table_outer
        GROUP BY
            parent_id
        HAVING
            COUNT(CASE WHEN ORIGIN NOT IN (1,2,4) THEN 1 END) = 0
            AND COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS NOT IN (10,20) THEN 1 END) = 0)
```

Comment: Can you share the exact output you are expecting?
Its confusing what you mean by --child 1 should come:

Comment: Thanks for reply, pls check the updated details.

Comment: "--Insert child for Parent5 should come"
The parent id for these inserts is 1. Is it supposed to be 5?

Comment: Yes updated one also not working which brings parent 4 too.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not checking the required conditions properly. 
For example; `COUNT(CASE WHEN ORIGIN NOT IN (1,2,4) THEN 1 END) = 0` is equivalent to checking that origin != reject.

If a particular parent has all origins as premiums/nonpremiums, it will not be filtered out with your condition origin != reject

Here is an alternate that does what you want.

```
select c.id as child_id, c.parent_id
from test_child c inner join test_parent p
on c.parent_id = p.id
where p.id in (
  select parent_id
  from (
    select parent_id,
    case when origin = 1 then 1 else 0 end as premium,
    case when origin = 2 then 1 else 0 end as fee,
    case when origin = 3 then 1 else 0 end as reject,
    case when origin = 4 then 1 else 0 end as m_premium,

    case when status = 10 then 1 else 0 end as pending,
    case when status = 20 then 1 else 0 end as cancelled,
    case when status = 30 then 1 else 0 end as submitted

    from  test_child c
  ) tmp 
  group by parent_id
  having sum(reject) = 0 and sum(fee) > 0
  and sum(pending) > 0 and sum(submitted) = 0
);
```